# How can I append an alement after another element?

Tags: jquery, append, insertafter

```
<div>
   <label for="form_username" class="required">Username</label>
   <input type="text" id="form_username" name="form[username]" required="required" class="form-control">
</div>
```

I try to append an element to the input field with the name "form[username]:

```
$( "<p>Test</p>" ).insertAfter('input[name=form[username]]');
```

But it is not working. Nothing happens.

I expect this result:

```
<div>
   <label for="form_username" class="required">Username</label>
   <input type="text" id="form_username" name="form[username]" required="required" class="form-control">
   <p>Test</p>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since your input tag has an id `form_username`, you don't have to use `[name]` attribute as a selector anymore.

```js
$( "<p>" ).text("Test").insertAfter('#form_username');
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div>
   <label for="form_username" class="required">Username</label>
   <input type="text" id="form_username" name="form[username]" required="required" class="form-control">
</div>
```

---

Or if you have only 1 input tag, you could try:

```js
$( "<p>" ).text("Test").insertAfter('input');
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div>
   <label for="form_username" class="required">Username</label>
   <input type="text" id="form_username" name="form[username]" required="required" class="form-control">
</div>
```

---

Or if you want to use attribute `name`, you could rename the value `form[username]` to `form_username`, like this:

```js
$( "<p>" ).text("Test").insertAfter('[name=form_username]');
$( "<p>" ).text("Test").insertAfter('input[name=form_username]');
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div>
   <label for="form_username" class="required">Username</label>
   <input type="text" id="form_username" name="form_username" required="required" class="form-control">
</div>
```

---

If you don't want to rename the `name` attribute value, you could try:

```js
$( "<p>" ).text("Test").insertAfter('input[name*="username"]');
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div>
   <label for="form_username" class="required">Username</label>
   <input type="text" id="form_username" name="form[username]" required="required" class="form-control">
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you! What if I cannot rename it. Is it then not possible?

Answer (score 0):

Alternatively, you could just use jQuery's `.append()` method to append your paragraph to your existing page elements.

```js
$('#content_one').append('<p>Test 1</p>');
$('#content_two').append('<p>Test 2</p>');
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="content_one">
  <label for="form_username" class="required">Username</label>
  <input type="text" id="form_username" name="form[username]" required="required" class="form-control">
</div>

<div id="content_two">
  <label for="form_password" class="required">Password</label>
  <input type="text" id="form_password" name="form[password]" required="required" class="form-control">
</div>
```

Comment: I have more than one div so I need to append it to the specific with the name form[username]